# Error with Format as Timespan in Datagridview

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm getting this error

[image]

with the following line of code

```
co.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "HH:mm"
```

co is defined as follows

```
Dim co As DataGridViewColumn = Me.Columns(fi.colDbName)
```

The error-message says that the Inputstring has the wrong format.

This line of code has been running for a couple of years now. Also, I didn't really make any changes with this app for the past year. So I assume it has something to do with either Windows 10 or VS 2015.

**Update:**
I think the problem might come from the different sql server version running on the test system.

Code works with

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Code does not work with

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (Intel X86)   Jun 10 2015 03:19:53   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Upate:
The column is defined as `Time(7)` in the database

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is the SqlDataType of the column containing Dates? if it is DataTime, What is the format of the stored Dates? If it is String, Have you changed the windows date format from the regional Settings?

Comment: If your .NET value is a `TimeSpan` then you have to provide a format string that is valid for `TimeSpans`, which yours is not.  I suggest that consult the documentation to learn what valid `TimeSpan` format strings look like.  They are NOT the same as for formatting `DateTimes` to time strings.

Comment: @jmcilhinney was right. Changing the formatstring to `hh\:mm` did the trick. Still leaves me wonderung why it was working for the past 10 years with `HH:mm`...

Comment: It's only relatively recently that `TimeSpans` have actually supported format strings.  If you check the documentation for the `TimeSpan.ToString` method, you'll see that the overload with no parameters is supported all the way back to .NET 1.1, while the overloads that accept a format string are only supported from .NET 4.0. Have you recently changed the targeted .NET version of your project? If "HH:mm" was working before then either it was simply being ignored or the `TimeSpan` was implicitly converted to a `DateTime` where now it's actually calling a method that requires a valid argument.